# nested IIf statement for calculated field

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2010

I have this formula in an Access table

```
iif([selling_unit_height]>[selling_unit_length],[selling_unit_height],[selling_unit_length],
iif([selling_unit_height]>[selling_unit_width],[selling_unit_height],[selling_unit_width],
iif([selling_unit_length]>[selling_unit_width],[selling_unit_length],[selling_unit_width])))
```

Can you not do something like this in Access? I have three numbers and I want to get the largest of the three numbers. It says wrong number of arguments. If I cannot do it this way, then I need help with another way to do it.

Comment: Is the formula for a field whose Data Type is "Calculated"?

Comment: I have it set to calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a formula which you can use as the *Expression* property for a field whose Data Type is *Calculated*.  (That means your db is an ACCDB type and your Access version is >= 2010.)

I used this as the *Expression* for a field named *largest* ...

```vb
IIf([h]>=[l] And [h]>=[w],[h],IIf([l]>=[h] And [l]>=[w],[l],IIf([w]>=[h] And [w]>=[l],[w],Null)))
```

It retrieves the largest value from those 3 fields (`h`, `l`, and `w`) or Null if any of them contain Null.

Here is a screenshot of the table with sample data ...

[image: datasheet view of table with calculated field]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this resource https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3, or try searching for "ms access iif"

You can nest your "Iif"s but your syntax is wrong.

```
iif(
 [selling_unit_height]>[selling_unit_length], # Condition
 [selling_unit_height],                       # true response
 iif(                                         # false response, a new iif
  [selling_unit_height]>[selling_unit_width], # condition
  [selling_unit_height],                      # true response
  iif(                                        # false response, a new iff
   [selling_unit_length]>[selling_unit_width],# condition
   [selling_unit_length],                     # true response
   [selling_unit_width]                       # final false response
  )
 )
)
```

I've not really considered the logic of what you are after, rather just highlighted the syntax mistakes.

Comment: i have height = 17 length = 1 width = 23. the largest of those numbers would. right now with that formula you just put in, it pulls the height =17, which is not the largest number

Comment: Then change your true response to check if the remaining alternative is greater with another iif. Out of interest what is your database table for? Perhaps a spreadsheet might be better.

Comment: i am using this for my company and i cant do it in a spreadsheet. what do you mean change the true response to check if the remaining alternative is greater with another iif? which true response?

Comment: i would think i can do if height > length and height > width then height else width if length > width then length